# Trying to run Java 8 on ChromeOS but keep running into error message

Tags: command-line, mount, java, chrome-os

I read from multiple websites that it's possible to download Java 8 on a Chromebook without having to use crouton. I do already have crouton but for matters of convenience, I wanted to be able to use Java 8 without having to switch over to Ubuntu. So, I read that all you to do is access the Chrome terminal and type "shell", press enter. Type "sudo su", press enter. Then, type "mount -o remount,exec,rw /" and press enter. I can't seem to get past this step though. Here's what I get after typing all of that:

```
crosh> shell

chronos@localhost / $ sudo su

localhost / # mount -o remount,exec,rw /

mount: cannot remount /dev/dm-0 read-write, is write-protected
```

I've tried looking this up, but I'm a novice programmer and just started learning how to use Linux. Needless to say, I can't keep up with some of the other forum posts that have asked similar questions.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable write protection to access the hard-drive to modify.  If you want to disable write protection, you are going to have to mess with the hardware. this might help
(this is model-specific)
https://gist.github.com/jcs/4bf59314d604538a5098

if you don't feel up to it, you can install ubuntu on the chromebook to switch OSes and install java on xfce4.
I've personally installed this, and I say this will work pretty good 
just make sure you are in dev channel, and follow the instructions
https://www.lifewire.com/install-linux-on-chromebook-4125253

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable RootFs (Root Filesystem) Verification to mount / as rw

```
sudo su -
crossystem dev_boot_signed_only=0
cd /usr/share/vboot/bin/
./make_dev_ssd.sh --remove_rootfs_verification --partitions 4
./make_dev_ssd.sh --remove_rootfs_verification --partitions 2
reboot
```

Breakdown:

1. `sudo su -`: Get root access
2. `crossystem dev_boot_signed_only=0` Allow booting of unsigned images (if /sbin/unix_update, etc is corrupted system will still boot)
3. `cd /usr/share/vboot/bin/` Change directory to required directory
4. `./make_dev_ssd.sh --remove_rootfs_verification --partitions 4` Remove RootFs Verification on partition 4
5. `./make_dev_ssd.sh --remove_rootfs_verification --partitions 2` Same thing as number 4 but on partition 2
6. `reboot` Reboot to apply changes

Note: Partition numbers may vary on your device. If you see this error message with N being the partition number you entered then you need to try again with another partition number.

```
make_dev_ssd.sh: INFO: Partition N: no kernel boot information, ignored.
make_dev_ssd.sh: ERROR: No valid kernel partitions on /dev/mmcblk0 (N).
```